# Remote Assistance for mobile users

Tags: android, windows-mobile, remote-desktop

One of our clients has about 100 users in the field with Windows Mobile 6.5 devices, with another 600 coming online soon that will be running a mix of Windows Mobile 6.5 and Android phones (I'm not sure which version of android, they're rolling them out at the end of the month).

We're having a lot of trouble with supporting these devices, because the users are tradies with large fingers who aren't very adept at using them. We're a subcontractor so we can't change their decision to roll out users with these phones.

Is there any software that will allow for a remote view of the users screen? We don't need to interact (but it would be nice), but we need to be able to spot their spelling errors etc that they're entering on screen.

They will be connected over HSPDA/3G 24/7 as they utilise a mobile web application for their daily work.

I expect the answers for Windows Mobile and Android will be totally different, so feel free to only answer one side if you can. It would be great if the cost is < $100/device.

Because of the large number of users, it would be great if each solution had some sort of a console or list of devices that displays all the available phones so that we don't have to get them to dig around and find their IP address.

Comment: What is tradies?

Comment: @Zoredache - tradesman - sorry slang. Plumbers, builders, tilers, concreters, etc

Comment: WinMobile 6.5?  Might as well get them to cut their throats now.

Comment: @Ward - don't get me started. I strongly opposed their purchase of the devices, but they're up to 300 of the horrible things now, and we're still having the same issues.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

For android you'll probably need the phones to be rooted. I don't know of a complete solution, but i have tested vnc server (currently needs to be launched from a console).

Comment: Ugh, there's no way these phones will be able to be rooted. The clients internal BIS team are about the most anal we've ever come across. I'll keep that in mind when explaining to them why we can't help their android users.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Logmein Rescue](https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/US/HelpDesk/SupportedDevices.aspx)?  No support yet for Android devices, although I'd imagine that's coming soon.  I can't speak to Rescue (although we're probably going to try it soon), but I use their other services and they're rock solid and invaluable.  Their support has been outstanding as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after spending 45 minutes on the phone today because someone couldn't spell correctly (or read correctly), I spent a lot more time reviewing all the available options; most of which seem to have been launched or promoted since I asked the original question:

- [LogMeIn Rescue](https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/US/HelpDesk/SupportedDevices.aspx) (as suggested by GregD). This is *ludicrasly* expensive for 300 devices.
- [EveryWan](http://www.sparus-software.com/en/product/everywan-overview/) - looks very, very promising, with fantastic pricing and Linux support. I can't wait to get their evaulation version deployed.
- [Bogmar Mobile](http://www.bomgar.com/mobile/) - again looks promising, but I can't find any indication of pricing on their website.

Answer (score 0):

The TeamViewer site indicates there is a mobile version which just might be worth a look. I use TeamViewer (free version) fairly regularly on desktops and find it quite good.

Comment: It looks like that allows you to access desktops from mobiles, but not the other way around. Still, I think I could find that quite useful as we have an iPad we use for remote admin from the road at the moment.